# Find number of objects inside an Item of DynomoDB table using Lamda function (Python/Node)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to the AWS world and I am in need to find the data count from a DynamoDB table. 
My table structure is like this.

1. It has 2 items (Columns in MySQL) say A and B
2. A - stores the (primary partition key) user ids.
3. B - stores the user profiles, number of profiles associated with a UserID.
4. Suppose A contains a user ID **3435** and it has 3 profiles ({"21btet3","3sd4","adf11"})
   My requirement is to get the count 3 to the output as a JSON in the format :

How to set the parameters for scanning this query? 
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

> DynamoDb is NoSQL so there are some limitations in terms of querying
>   the data. In your case you have to scan the entire table like below

```
def ScanDynamoData(lastEvalutedKey):
    table =  boto3.resource("dynamodb", "eu-west-1").Table('TableName') #Add your region and table name
    if lastEvalutedKey:
        return table.scan(
            ExclusiveStartKey=lastEvalutedKey
        )
    else:
        return table.scan()
```

And call this method in a loop until lastEvalutedKey is null (To scan all the records) like

```
response = ScanDynamoData(None);
totalUserIds = response["Count"] 
#In response you will get the json of entire table you can count userid and profiles here

while "LastEvaluatedKey" in response:
        response = ScanDynamoData(response["LastEvaluatedKey"])
        totalUserIds += response["Count"]
        #Add counts here also
```

Answer (score 0):

**you should not do full table scan on a regular basis.**

If you requirement is to get this count frequently, you should subscribe a [lambda function](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) to [dynamodb streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html)  and update the count as and when new records are inserted into dynamodb. This will make sure

1. you are paying less
2. you will not have to do table scan to calculate this number.